# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Magento Admin Section:
Shopping Cart Price Rule

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
·         Subtotal  equals or greater than  50

Question:

If the total is above 50euros then 20% discount but in the total, I need the exclude items which has already discounted prices 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the `Special Price` attribute is available for use with Promo Rules:

1. Go to **Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes** and choose the attribute **Special Price**
2. Set the option **Use for Promo Rule Conditions** to `Yes` and then click **Save Attribute**
3. Be sure to reindex Magento and clear your caches.

Now go edit your Shopping Cart Price Rule.

On the conditions tab, set it as such:

[image: Promo Conditions]

On the actions, set it as such:

[image: Promo Actions]

The key is the actions tab.  The rule reads "Apply the rule only to items matching the following conditions.  If ALL of these conditions are FALSE, apply the rule to the item".  If the item DOES NOT (False) have a Special Price value greater than 0 in the Special Price field, it is assumed that this product is not on sale and will be discounted by the rule.